# Calculate autocorrelation with lag u in R

Tags: r, statistics

Hi I tried calculating autocorrelation with lag u, u = 1...9

I expect 9x1 autocorrelation functions. However when I try to use this code it always gave me 10x1 autocorrelation function with the first term = 1. I am not sure how to proceed.

```
# initialize a vector to store autocovariance
maxlag <- 9
varstore <- rep(NA,maxlag)
# Calculate Variance
varstore[1] <- sd(as.vector(sample1),na.rm=T)^2

# Estimate autocovariances for all residuals
for (lag in 1:maxlag)
  varstore[lag+1] <- mean(sample1[,1:(10-lag)] * 
                         sample1[,(lag+1):10],na.rm=T)
print(round(varstore,3))
# calculate autocorrelations
corrstore <- varstore/varstore[1]
print(corrstore)
```

And this is what I get:

```
[1] 1.0000000 0.6578243 0.5670389 0.5292314 0.5090411 0.4743944 0.4841038 0.4756297
[9] 0.4275208 0.4048436
```

Comment: What is `sample1`? Also youshouldputmorespacesinyourcode (like I've edited now).

Answer (score 3):

You get a vector of length 10 because of the recycling.

for  `lag =maxlog` ( the last step of your `for` loop)

```
  varstore[lag+1]
```

will create a new entry with NA. To see this clearly, try this for example :

```
v <- NA      ## a vector of length 1
v[10] <- 2
v
[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  2   ## you get a vector of legnth 10!!
```

That'said , why do you want a vector of length 9? Why not to use the `acf` function? Here the output of the `acf` function:

```
length(acf(1:10)$lag)
[1] 10
```